# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (No connection pool with 'primary' found.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

The postgresql table looks like:

```
      id |                  name                   | size |              md5sum
     ----+-----------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------
       1 |         MyPreferredGenomeName           | 1000 | df768fde8e10e15511c41895363bcce6
```

I am trying to retrieve the data:

```
myData = myClass.find_by name: "MyPreferredGenomeName" # also tried with other columns
# or 
myData = myClass.where name: "MyPreferredGenomeName"
```

and I get the error stated in the title from `activerecord-5.2.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1032:in` retrieve_connection'`.

I don't have the most basic understanding of what's going on... Help.

Also, what does 'primary' stand for?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your `config/database.yml` is not configured correctly.

In that file you should have something similar to:

```
...
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: database_name_development
...
```

You want to make sure that `database_name_development` is the name of the database in your local PostgreSQL instance. Is your database actually called `primary` as that is what the error seems to be saying.

You show the psql output with the table named `MyPreferredGenomeName` so whatever database that is in is needed in `database.yml`.

You can test what database Rails is looking for with:

```
rails console
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
=> "database_name_development"
```

(Do not post any secrets in any replies e.g. db passwords or full connection strings.)